# Rails 4 view rendering extra object in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have comments as a subresource of articles, as below:

```
resources :articles do
    resources :comments
end
```

I want each Article's show page to display all of its corresponding comments, as well as have a form where a user (if signed in) can create a new comment that corresponds with the article.

Here's the show action for `ArticlesController`:

```
  def show
    @comment = @article.comments.build
    if user_signed_in?
      @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    end
    respond_with(@article)
  end
```

Here's relevant code from the `CommentsController`:

```
 before_action :set_article

 ...

 def create
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment successfully created!"
    end
    redirect_to @article
  end

  ...

 private

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

  end
```

And here's the Article show view:

```
<b>Post comments:</b><br />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User email</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= comment.user.email %></td>
        <td><%= comment.body %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />

<%= form_for ([@article, @comment]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Compose new comment..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

**Here's the two situations I need to fix:**

1. When no user is signed in, the view fails to render because comment.user returns nil
2. When a user is signed in, a phantom comment for each article appears, because the `show` action in the ArticlesController is building a new (empty) comment with @comment = @article.comments.build

What is the best way to simultaneously solve both of these problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do that in the view, you can do this sort of thing in the controller.

```
def show
  @comment = Comment.new(:article => @article)
  respond_with(@article)
end
```

This won't add the comment to the article.comments array and won't try to render a blank comment.

Do you need to set the user_id on the comment in the form on the show action?  If not, you can do this in create

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @comment.article = @article
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Comment successfully created!"
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render :show
  end

end
```

The benefit to this - you can now handle errors in the form (like if they submit a blank comment, or minimum characters).  Even if you handle it in the view with javascript/disabled buttons, it's nice to have the server also support validations and errors.

Comment: I was gonna say the same about the user_id part, because the way it was done allows anyone to inject a comment using a random person's name by changing the user_id in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just kidding, got it.

Put the `build` call into the form rather than the `ArticleController`:

```
<%= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Compose new comment..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

and delete everything out of the show action:

```
  def show
    respond_with(@article)
  end
```